# Can't change color of Card Title text in React Native Paper

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-paper, card

I'm just getting started with React Native and using Paper for UI elements. I'm using a card layout for my current screen:

```
{cardData.map((card, index) => {
    return(
    <Card key={index}>
      <Card.Title title="Card Title" subtitle="Subtitle" style={styles.cardHeader} />
      <Card.Content>
        <Paragraph>{card.content}</Paragraph>
      </Card.Content>
      <Card.Cover source={{ uri: 'https://picsum.photos/700' }} />
      <Card.Actions>
        <Button>Cancel</Button>
        <Button>Ok</Button>
      </Card.Actions>
    </Card>
    )
})}
```

I'm trying to change the color of the title section to green, an the color of the text to white. So I have the following style:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  cardHeader: {
    backgroundColor: '#00bc8c',
    color: '#ffffff'
  }
});
```

Strangely the background color changes as expected, but the text color remains black. Could anyone suggest why this may be the case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use titleStyle for styling title [react-native-paper](https://callstack.github.io/react-native-paper/card-title.html#titleStyle)

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by Nooruddin, but with a code sample:

```
titleStyle={{ color: "#f00" }}
```